# Is it possible to buy weapon attachment modifications?

Tags: weapons, star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars

In SWEotE, according to core rules, you *buy* weapon attachments / add-ons - as many as the weapon has slots are possible.

You can then *modify* them by spending 100 credits and passing a hard (3x purple die) mechanics check.

Is it possible to *buy* a modification through an NPC mechanic/shop keeper (that is to have the skilled NPC do the check)? What would this cost in addition to the 100 credits?

Answer (score 2):

**You Can.**

On Page 91 of Special Modification, table 3-20 "Crafting sell price" includes the line "adding a mod to an item attachment": cost 500 credits x difficulty of the check, and takes less than a day. The cost does not include the price of the item and original attachment.

Please consider that this is a base price if the PC is selling this service. If the PC is buying this work, this might be subject to availability, rarity/restriction, and negotiation of the price.

As a personal rule, since PC might sell an item up to 75% of the regular price (not including rarity), I would add at least a 25% of the price provided in the table, or increasing the number of days.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a specific rule from EotE to quote so I can't say whether it's possible or not (only your GM can!) but if it is I find in general a 100% markup is a good approximation.

From experience with Pathfinder, creating magic items costs half as much as buying them and I think that makes a good comparison for this situation - choosing between either creating something yourself for a certain amount of money + skills, or doubling the price and getting it from someone else.

Of course the old "ask your GM" applies, mainly because in this case they might want to tweak the markup or let you know just how available such services are.

Answer (score 1):

The rule that I have used in my FFG Star Wars game is generally that players can access services from a professional for whatever it would cost a player to do themselves plus an appropriate service charge (usually determined by a negotiate roll, where failures increase the total cost by a percentage of the base).

Usually, these services are offered by an NPC who has 2 skill ranks and 2 points in a relevant ability, for a total of 2 proficiency dice on the skill roll (they are often outsourcing Mechanics jobs for their ships or weapons). Sometimes the players will assist the mechanic or professional if one of them has a high ability but low skill.

Availability/cost of these skills is going to vary depending on location and rarity. There aren't any hard rules on this (to the best of my knowledge). I tend to consider Mechanic a fairly universal skill in Star Wars, while Computers is a little less available in the Outer Rim (i.e. will cost more, or might be unavailable if it is convenient for the plot). Skills like Lore are going to much harder to find an expert in.

At your discretion, highly skilled professionals might be available, with skill ranks of 3 or 4 (I tend not to have skill 5 NPCs just wandering around).

Pricing of these services is really going to vary a lot. If the players can find a vendor who likes them, they'll likely get a good rate or even be able to barter favors. If the players are fugitives, rebels, etc. then they'll face higher costs because doing business with them is likely risky. Organized crime can have favored access to certain services as well. Lots of great narrative and plot hooks available here.